# Delete a file from a jar file without using zip command or extracting the jar

Tags: zip, 7-zip, jar, winzip, uss

Is there a way to delete the file from a jar file without extracting it or without using the 'zip' command?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want an alternative solution of "zip my.jar -d unwanted_file" command.

Comment: you won't be able to do this without third party tools. why have you discounted using zip or another tool?